# Is there any alternative to \Sexpr{} to write a matrix object in R?

Tags: r, sweave, r-exams

The function `\Sexpr{}` does not recognize matrix object. For example, I am setting an exam question using 'exams' package in R. I have two objects generated via R commands 1. **opt.obj.val** 2. **opt.sol**. The object **opt.obj.val** returns scalar value while **opt.sol** returns matrix object. I want to use these two objects in the solution part of the question. `\Sexpr{}` is fine with scalar value such as **opt.obj.val** object. However, it does not recognize **opt.sol** which is a matrix object.  Is it possible to use `\Sexpr{}` to retrieve matrix object or is there any alternative command?

```
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
library(lpSolve)
P1 <- c(11, 12,  10, 9)
P2 <- c(6,  7,  500,   3)
P3 <- c(8,  8.5, 7.5, 9.5)
costs <- rbind(P1, P2, P3)
row.signs <- rep("=", 3) 
row.rhs <- c(30, 30, 30) # rhs values of rows  
col.signs <- rep("=", 4)
col.rhs <- c(15, 25, 40, 10) # rhs values of columns
opt.obj.val <- lp.transport(costs, "min", row.signs, row.rhs, col.signs, col.rhs)$objval
opt.sol <- lp.transport(costs, "min", row.signs, row.rhs, col.signs, col.rhs)$solution
@

\begin{question}
a) What is the optimal objective function value?
\begin{answerlist}
  \item \Sexpr{opt.obj.val} 
  \item 780 
  \item 350 
  \item 560
  \item 710
\end{answerlist}
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\begin{answerlist}
  \item True.
  \item False.
  \item False.
  \item False.
  \item False.
\end{answerlist}

The optimal objective function value is \Sexpr{opt.obj.val}.

The optimal solution is \Sexpr{opt.sol}.

\end{solution}

\exname{Transportation}
\extype{schoice}
\exsolution{10000}
\exshuffle{TRUE}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:** Use `\Sexpr{toLatex(opt.sol)}` instead of `\Sexpr{opt.sol}`.

**Examples:** [hessian](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/hessian/) and [cholesky](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/cholesky/), provided within the package.

**Details:**

- The `\Sexpr{x}` command is mainly intended for embedding atomic vectors of length 1 into LaTeX documents. As matrices are atomic vectors (with a dim attribute), only the first element of the matrix is displayed with a warning that only the first element was selected.
- The function `toLatex()` is a generic function with methods for a couple of classes of objects. The `exams` package provides the method for `matrix` objects. If you look at the output `toLatex(opt.sol)` you see that it returns a single character string with a straightforward `{array}`.
- By default, the `toLatex(x)` method escapes all backslashes twice so that they can be conveniently used inside `\Sexpr{}`. In case the function is used outside `\Sexpr{}`, e.g., in an R/Markdown exercise, then `toLatex(x, escape = FALSE)` needs to be used.

Comment: Dear Achim, Thanks a lot! Since the matrix is a math environment it works with $ sign as $\Sexpr{toLatex(opt.sol)}$.